# Why should we attach model before update in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, change-tracking

I have question about the change tracker in Entity Framework. I read the change tracker document on MSDN - it said that if you insert a model into a database, its status in context will be `Added`, and when you execute `SaveChanges()`, it inserts a new row into the database and its status becomes `unchanged`.

So why should we attach a model before updating it in Entity Framework?

```
public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
{
    _dbset.Attach(entity); => ???
    _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Update** :

[image: My Project Structure]

[image: My Code in Repository]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While an entity is altered within the scope of a DbContext, and was not loaded /w `AsNoTracking`, the change tracker for that DbContext will pick up changes and apply updates when you call `SaveChanges`. As in the example you've given, in many cases you might be dealing with an Entity that currently *isn't* tracked by a DbContext anymore.

As a simple example: (Tracked entities)

```
public void UpdateDescription(int orderId, string description)
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var order = context.Orders.Single(x => x.OrderId == orderId);
        order.Description = description;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

In this example, the Order entity is loaded, tracked, and updated within the scope of a single DbContext.  Instead, if we have a method structure like this:

```
public Order GetOrderById(int orderId)
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        return context.Orders.Single(x => x.OrderId == orderId);
    }
}

public void UpdateOrder(Order order)
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        context.Attach(order);
        context.Entity(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Such as in the case of web applications where an Edit page retrieves an Order entity and passes that to a view. When the user updates some fields on the page Model and submits, a separate Update call is made passing the model. With the "GetOrderById" call, the Order entity was loaded by one instance of the DbContext. When the "UpdateOrder" call occurs, that Order is effectively a deserialized POCO, not a tracked entity anymore. This would be why you need to attach it to the DbContext instance that Update will be using, and set it's entity state to Modified in order for EF to treat it as an entity that needs to be updated.

It is worth noting that in the first tracked example, the UPDATE SQL statement will effectively be something like:

```
UPDATE Orders SET Description = 'newDescription' WHERE OrderId = 1
```

where in the second example, the UPDATE statement would be more like:

```
UPDATE Orders SET OrderNumber = 21, CustomerId = 12, Description = 'newDescription' /* + all fields/FKs in Order table... */ WHERE OrderId = 1
```

By attaching and setting an entity state to Modified, EF will update *all* non-PK properties on the entity, even if you only intend/expect for one field to have been modified. In the case of a web application, passing entities back to a controller to be updated this way can leave your system vulnerable to data tampering. (Changing fields/FKs that your UI did not allow) It also means you need to pass a complete entity all of the time to avoid data possibly getting wiped unexpectedly which increases the message payload size going back and forth between client and server.

Comment: So, In **DeleteOrder** method why should we check that if the model is detached then you attach it, But in **UpdateOrder** method we attach it anymore(without checking that is attached or not).

Comment: Without seeing your code and how it is used I doubt anyone can answer whether it is required or not.  If the code is structured in a way that it could be called with either attached or detached entities and an injected DbContext then it likely should be checked for both delete and update scenarios. With Delete specifically you can get away with creating a new entity instance with just the PK populated and tell the DbContext to delete it. However if the DbContext could already be tracking that entity (such as related to another loaded entity) that would raise an exception. Hence a check added?

Comment: That would be a question for whoever wrote that generic Repository. Was it based on an example? Given that implementation I'd expect to see a check on the Update as well as the Delete. Working with detached entities can be a bit more complicated than that. Their check only assumes the entity is associated to *a* DbContext, not necessarily the same instance of the DbContext or if the DbContext is already tracking another reference to the same entity. (I.e. another entity object for the same row) Depending on how the methods are called, bugs like that can creep in.

Comment: So it means, it's better to check on both Update and Delete methods.

Comment: Yes, whenever dealing with a potentially detached entity you should check whether the entity is currently tracked by a DbContext and whether the current DbContext is already tracking another entity reference with the same ID. Reattaching detached entities will work fine 95% of the time but as apps evolve they can easily introduce scenarios where you get errors due to assumptions about the attached state or other tracked instances which lead to almost random-like runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

Because `EntityFramework` only changed entities that exist in [`ChangeTracker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker?view=efcore-3.1).

And when you Attaching an entity to `DbContext`, entity framework know that one entity has tracked and maybe contains changes and apply changes in `DataBase` after `SaveChanges`.

Comment: So, In "Delete" method in Repsository, First we check if model is detached then attach it. But in "Update" method we attach it anyway (Without checking that the model is attached or not.).